# in my situation, Error inserting a record into database table using MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE FLIGHT
(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
FLIGHT_NO VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
OPERATING_AIRLINES VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
DEPARTURE_CITY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
ARRIVAL_CITY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
DATE_OF_DEPARTURE DATE NOT NULL,
ESTIMATED_DEPARTURE_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)
```

when i do:

```
insert into flight values
(1,'AA1','American Airlines','AUS','NYC', STR_TO_DATE('02-05-2018','%m-%d-%y'), '2018-02-05 03:14:07')
```

getting this error:

> Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect date value: '02-05-2018'    0.000 sec

Comment: `%y` is for 2-digit years. Use `%Y` for 4-digit years.